# Freeform upload size error is wrong

Tags: plugin-freeform, solspace, freeform

having an issue with Solspace Freeform. I have a form with 2 file fields. The max file size has been increased to 20Mb, Nginx/PHP/Craft have all been increased to 20Mb too but yet  when I try to upload a 10MB file, the error says the max file size is 2048Kb.

Not quite sure where that's coming from or more importantly why this is. Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Default max size for a Freeform upload field is

    const DEFAULT_MAX_FILESIZE_KB = 2048;

Its expecting KB. What did you add to the Max file size in the freeform options for that field?

Answer (score 1):

turned out I'd forgotten I hardcoded the form validation options from the render tag and didn't update the validation